# how can i get the retrofit response in return value?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin

**How Can I solve this Problem**
I want to return value when we use retrofit in android

```
fun login():String
     {
    .enqueue(object :Callback<List<ANY>>
    {
        override fun on Failure(call: Call<List<ANY>>, t: Throwable) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun on Response(
            call: Call<List<ANY>>,
            response: Response<List<ANY>>
        ) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
    return " ? "; // how to return retrofit response
}
```

Comment: [you can use this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: The option is to use a callback(interface) to nofity the result when is recevied from retrofit.

Comment: Since result is not available at the same time request is created, it is asynchronous. You may use coroutines to return the result, but you should just use them inside instead of returning, or maybe accept a lambda parameter in the login function that will be invoked at the time of the result has came.